# gcc delegate converting warning

Tags: c++, gcc

Имеем:

```
  typedef void (*xbswap)(unsigned char*, long unsigned int);
  void xClass::BSwap(BYTE*, DWORD);
```

Функция:

```
  static bool fun1(xbswap cb_swap) { ... }
```

Вызываем из класса xClass:

```
  fun1((xbswap)&BSwap));
```

И в месте вызова имеем предупреждение:

```
 warning: converting from 'void (xClass::*)(BYTE*, DWORD)'
 {aka 'void (xClass::*)(unsigned char*, long unsigned int)'} to 'xbswap' 
 {aka 'void (*)(unsigned char*, long unsigned int)'} [-Wpedantic]
  ...
```

Как разумно поправить? кроме выключения варнинга..

Comment: Нужен указатель не на функцию, а указатель на  функцию_член

Comment: `xClass::BSwap` ведь статическая функция-член?

Comment: @Fat-Zer Не похоже, раз компилятор ругается на `void (xClass::*)(...)`.

Comment: Да, вроде статичная функция. Это вы имеете в виду поправить в typedef? Не совсем понял про указатель.

Comment: Никак разумно не поправить. Нестатичнские функции-члены принципиально неконвертируемы к указателям на обычные функции. Более того `&BSwap` - такого синтаксиса для нестатической функции-члена в С++ не поддерживается вообще.

Comment: @Ant, а иные пути решения присутствуют? bind ?

Comment: `bind` вам в результате даст функциональный объект, а не указатель на функцию. Реентерабельных способов превратить указатель на метод в указатель на функцию в С++ нет. Переходите, если можете, с указателя на функцию на `std::function` и тогда и `bind` заработает.

Comment: Понятно, спасибо, если не затруднит, пример был бы весьма полезен.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если у вас есть полная свобода в выборе интерфейса вашего `static bool fun1(...)`, то вы можете изначально реализовать ее через функтор, а не через указатель на функцию. Либо

```
template <typename F>
static bool fun1(F cb_swap) // или const F &cb_swap
{
  ...
  cb_swap(byte_ptr, dw);
  ...
}
```

либо

```
static bool fun1(const std::function<void (BYTE*, DWORD)> &cb_swap)
{
  ...
  cb_swap(byte_ptr, dw);
  ...
}
```

Первый вариант более эффективен, но за это приходится платить "размножением" `foo`: отдельной версией `foo` для каждого значения шаблонного параметра `F`. Вторая версия не является шаблонной, т.е. не "размножается" для разных типов аргументов, но за это приходится платить внутренними накладными расходами `std::function`.

Тогда у вас будет полная свобода в конструировании этого функционального объекта для передачи в `fun1`, включая использование `std::bind`

```
// Внутри метода `xClass`
using namespace std::placeholders;
fun1(std::bind(&xClass::BSwap, this, _1, _2));
```

По таким причинам в С++ рекомендуется сразу проектировать интерфейсы в терминах функциональных объектов (а не указателей на функции) всегда, когда это возможно. Это не всегда возможно: интерфейсы могут быть навязаны посторонним кодом, в т.ч. написанным на С. Но если в данном случае вы контролируете весь код, то такую возможность стоит рассмотреть.

Comment: Спасибо, красивая реализация